# Ansible Strict Host Key Checking when spawned from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, ansible

I am trying to run ansible as a spawned process from NodeJS.

I have tried everything I can find on the internet and on StackOverflow to prevent ansible from doing Strict Host Key Checking when logging in via SSH, however ansible is just ignoring all the settings.

I have set the environment variable

```
export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False
```

I have added to `~/.ssh/config

```
Host *
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

I have added `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False` to my nodejs .env file.

As an example of the command I am running, here is some of my code.

```js
function runPlaybook(playbook, ip) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let ansible = spawn('ansible-playbook', [`-i ${ip},`, playbook]);

    ansible.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stderr: ' + data.toString());
    });

    ansible.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      let stdoutData = data.toString();
      console.log('stdout: ', stdoutData);
      if (stdoutData.includes(`ok: [${ip}]`)) {
        console.log('Clearning Interval');
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
      if (stdoutData.startsWith(ip)) {
        const re =
          /^[0-9.]* *: *ok=([0-9])* *changed=([0-9])* *unreachable=([0-9])* *failed=([0-9])* *skipped=([0-9])* *rescued=([0-9])* *ignored=([0-9])*/gm;
        var m;
        while ((m = re.exec(stdoutData))) {
          const result = {
            ok: parseInt(m[1]),
            changed: parseInt(m[2]),
            unreachable: parseInt(m[3]),
            failed: parseInt(m[4]),
            skipped: parseInt(m[5]),
            rescued: parseInt(m[6]),
            ignored: parseInt(m[7]),
          };
          if (result.unreachable + result.failed == 0) {
            return resolve(result);
          } else {
            return reject(result);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Just can't think of anything else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by using the correct key file, embarrassing I know, however the error I was getting from SSH was very similar if not the same as you would get if the host had changed. In this case, it had. I was deleting VM's on my virtual server and recreating them, I must be the only person working at the moment because the same IP address was available and kept being reissued to new VM's. However at the same time due to a refactor I had also changed the key I was pointing to.

As an upside, feel free to use my regex in the example code to get the Ansible results into an array.